# react-redux - ReferenceError: g is not defined

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I found this problem when was building javascript files for production and I test the Website again. In the development environment I can not reproduce.
I am using react and react-redux on my SinglePageApplication, npm and gulp building tool.

**package.json:**

```
"react": "~16.0.0",
"react-chartjs-2": "^2.6.4",
"react-dom": "~16.0.0",
"react-dropzone": "^4.1.3",
"react-popper": "^0.7.3",
"react-redux": "~4.4.0",
```

**versions**

```
react -v : 16.3.0
react-redux -v : 4.4.9
```

**Gulp command**

```
npm -i
gulp production
```

I got an error message from the browser:

```
react-redux.min.js? 3b99:1 Uncaught     

ReferenceError: g is not defined
        at a (react-redux.min.js?3b99:1)
        at a (react-redux.min.js?3b99:1)
        at react-redux.min.js?3b99:1
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @DanielA.White thanks for your feedback. I now did so and edited the comment. Cheers!

Comment: where's your code that can reproduce it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got 2 days ago same problem in my project without touching the code only build the code.
Is a general problem issue in the minifier react-redux.min for version 4.4.9 ; I suggest to put in the package.json a fix version for `react-redux`: '4.4.8'

There is a issue ticket with this problem but they closed it, I hope they will reopen and try to fix for the version 4.4.9
https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/904